# Remove Facebook Login from your Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am programming a little web application right now. At some point I need to thing about the user registration. My first thought was do it with a Facebook Authentication. Why? I think it's easier to get user like that, because most of them have already an account on Facebook and don't want to get over the usual registration form(EMail Confirmation, ..).

Now I am asking myself, what happens when I decide to cut of the connection between Facebook and my WebApp? I mean maybe at some point I do not want to be dependent on facebook. Can I easily remove the Facebook Authentication and keep the already registered User? I think the biggest issue would be to set a new password instead using the Facebook ones for the User.

Comment: You could send all users an email with an auto-generated password or a token, that they can use once to log into your site and then immediately change/set their password. Problem with that, you will not get email addresses for all users from Facebook, so you would have to ask those to input an email address after they register using FB.

Comment: Or you could only remove Facebook login “in general”, but still offer it as an option for users that do not yet have a password set after you “officially” end supporting FB login. To force users to set a password then, you could make the FB login only a “login light”, that will _only_ allow them to set a password, and use none of the other features that your site offers for users that are logged in the “regular” way using a password.

Comment: Oh and of course you will need to have a username (or some other identifier to be used in combination with the password) set for the user in your database already – and the user has to know it as well (OK, not if you go with the token method). Again, using their email will only work if you make sure that you _have_ an email on file for all users, so you will need to ask some of them to actively input it themselves. All in all, quite a bit of a hassle and extra complexity on your part … maybe easier to just _keep_ FB login after all.